# Does "pulchritudinous" have a negative connotation?

Tags: word-meaning

When somebody says:

> That girl is pulchritudinous.

Does it have a negative connotation?

According to Merriam-Webster ["pulchritudinous sounds more disgusting than enchanting"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/top-10-unusually-long-words-vol-2)

Comment: Does anyone actually use such a word? Do you have a notable usage for it?

Comment: You will rarely if ever encounter this word and its use is best avoided. Subjectively I would agree that it is an ugly word that means "beautiful".

Answer (score 2):

There is no logical reason why Pulchritudinous should have a negative implication.

The original latin word is "pulchra"- an adjective, which then gets converted to "pulchritude" a noun and then "pulchritudinous" - an adjective. Repeatedly adding endings like this in order to go full circle- adjective-noun-adjective-  probably seems unpleasant to an etymologist, just as a carpenter might find a piece of repeatedly-botched woodwork unpleasant.

The pu- sound to my mind is not very pleasant: I feel the same about the word pudding. In addition, the "lch" letter combination is quite difficult to say...

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't have a negative connotation, but just try saying to the next woman you see "My, you look particularly pulchritudinous this morning!" and you're likely to end up with a black eye.

Comment: @JohnClifford because it's vulgar? in fact, it means that somebody is physically beautiful, yes?

Comment: @Student it does, but I don't think a huge number of people are aware of that. :)